# Prevent consecutive read operations from memory in C from being optimized away

Tags: c, memory, compiler-optimization, volatile, read-access

My goal is to iterate memory on a microcontroller in C, and do two consecutive read operations on each cell, testing if both are zero. I try to do this as follows:

```
volatile uint8_t* memory = MEMORY_START_ADDR;

for(uint8_t byte = 0; byte < MEM_SIZE_IN_BYTES; byte ++)
{
      if(memory[byte] != 0) do_something();
      if(memory[byte] != 0) do_something();  // check same location again
}
```

Now I want to make sure that the second read operation is not optimized away by the compiler.

From my understanding, writing `volatile uint8_t * memory = ...` marks the object `*memory` as volatile, so two accesses at least to `memory[0]` shouldn't be optimized away. Does that also apply for all consecutive accesses to `*(memory + byte)`?

Comment: In this case nothing would be optimized away even if `memory` is not volatile. And practically there should be no undefined behaviour here, at least I'm not aware of any C compiler that would do that.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I assumed that would be a perfect example for compiler optimization, no? Two consecutive reads on a location that does not seem to change in between.

Comment: @Cramstyler oh, sorry, I misread the code, you're right. But `volatile` should prevent optimisation.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I got caught as well. The inner loop reads `memory[byte]` twice in a row

Comment: @Jabberwocky Right. `volatile` is needed if one expect this memory to change by some external means

Comment: To your question, `memory + byte` has the same type of `memory`, including the `volatile` qualifier.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what `volatile` is for.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks, I was looking for explicit confirmation of that. :)

Comment: BTW, I'd take back my comment regarding this access being undefined behavior. This location *might* contain an *object*, while C standard does not restrict the definition of *object* to objects created by the C program itself. This object may belong to the execution environment.